# Mountain lion nssharing service

Tags: cocoa, service, share

I have been looking into NSShareService and I would like to make a new service, but one that would be available from everywhere. I have really been looking but I can't find any such information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write one that is available from everywhere, sadly. You can only write ones that are available within your own app.